# Android: Maven final archive name

Tags: android, maven, jenkins, android-build, maven-install-plugin

At the end of a maven `mvn clean install` run, the created artifacts are automatically installed in the repository by the maven-install-plugin:

```
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ project ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\mannaz\workspace\project\target\project-0.1.1-test.apk to C:\Users\mannaz\.m2\repository\at\mannaz\android\project\0.1.1\project-0.1.1.apk
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\mannaz\workspace\project\pom.xml to C:\Users\mannaz\.m2\repository\at\mannaz\android\project\0.1.1\project-0.1.1.pom
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\mannaz\workspace\project\target\project-0.1.1-test.jar to C:\Users\mannaz\.m2\repository\at\mannaz\android\project\0.1.1\project-0.1.1.jar
```

Unfortunately the final apk filename is renamed during this process (`project-0.1.1-test.apk`>>`project-0.1.1.apk`).

Initially the name of the apk file is set via

```
<finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${webservice.target}</finalName>
```

How can I specify the final name of the apk file in the build archive without overriding the `<version/>` attribute itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Reason:

Running `mvn clean install -X` cause Maven execute `default-install` goal at the end of the [build life cycle](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/maven-core/lifecycles.html#default_Lifecycle), which use the default groupId:artifactId:packaging:version install the generated apk (I use `abc-123` as the final name in this example):

```
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.1:install (default-install) @ myapp ---
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.1:install from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.1, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@11b86e7]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.1:install' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) artifact = com.mycompany:myapp:apk:1.2.2-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG]   (f) attachedArtifacts = [com.mycompany:myapp:jar:1.2.2-SNAPSHOT]
[DEBUG]   ... ...
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] Installing C:\workspace\myapp\target\abc-123.apk to c:\maven\repository\com\mycompany\myapp\1.2.2-SNAPSHOT\myapp-1.2.2-SNAPSHOT.apk
[INFO] ... ...
```

### Solution:

This default artifact install is AFAIK neither avoidable nor modifiable, and the `<finalName>` doesn't take any effect on the target file name (which use a fixed pattern `artifactId-version-classifier.packaging`) during the  default-install goal execution. The solution is attach extra artifact to the build life cycle, depend on you demand (If you only need add some suffix behind `myapp-1.2.2-SNAPSHOT`), the easiest way is define a [classifier](http://maven-android-plugin-m2site.googlecode.com/svn/apk-mojo.html#classifier) in android-maven-plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
  <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <extensions>true</extensions>
  <configuration>
    <classifier>test</classifier>
    ... ...
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This will cause both myapp-1.2.2-SNAPSHOT.apk and myapp-1.2.2-SNAPSHOT-test.apk get installed into maven repository:

```
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.1:install (default-install) @ myapp ---
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.1:install from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.1, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@11b86e7]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.1:install' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) artifact = com.mycompany:myapp:apk:1.2.2-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG]   (f) attachedArtifacts = [com.mycompany:myapp:jar:1.2.2-SNAPSHOT, com.mycompany:myapp:apk:test:1.2.2-SNAPSHOT]
[DEBUG]   ... ...
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] Installing C:\workspace\myapp\target\abc-123.jar to c:\maven\repository\com\mycompany\myapp\1.2.2-SNAPSHOT\myapp-1.2.2-SNAPSHOT.apk
[INFO] ... ...
[INFO] Installing C:\workspace\myapp\target\abc-123.apk to c:\maven\repository\com\mycompany\myapp\1.2.2-SNAPSHOT\myapp-1.2.2-SNAPSHOT-test.apk
```